# Login/Home pages not destroyed when login/logout in Ionic 5 router

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, angular-routing, ionic5

My project is in IONIC 5 and Firstore. There are 2 different `ion-router-outlet` for authenticated (Home) and unauthenticated (Index) routes. Following is the code for dynamically opening the login/home page for users in class `app.component.ts`.

```
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('index');
    }
  });
```

Flow: Login Page -> (login) -> Home Page -> (logout) ->  Login Page. When the Home page is open the Login page is still loaded and in the navigation stack. The `ngOnDestroy` of the Login page does not execute. After the logout, the Login page opens again but the class `constructor` and `ngOnInit` method does not execute. This is causing a lot of issues as the page initialization is not reloading. The same issue happening for flow Home Page -> (logout) -> Login Page -> (login) ->  Home Page. 
How can I destroy the Login page after login and Home page after logout so that those can reload if reopened in the same session?

**EDIT:**

Following is the routing config:

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'index',
    loadChildren: () => import('./index/index.module').then(m => m.IndexPageModule)
  },
];
```

Both the `Home.html` and `Index.html` has the same following code.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

index-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndexPage,
    children:[
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage,
    children:[
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/user/user.module').then( m => m.UserPageModule)
      },
.....
Other authenticated pages
]
```

Comment: can you show your route config?

Comment: I added in the original post.  Thx.

Comment: Instead of `ngOnDestroy` and `ngOnInit`, can't you use the hooks available on an ionic page life cycle: `ionViewWillEnter()`, `ionViewDidEnter()`, `ionViewWillLeave` and `ionViewDidLeave`?

Comment: @TapasMukherjee where are your two router outlets placed?

Comment: @AakashGarg Inside scr>app folder there are two folders created for home and index. I created these using ionic g page. The routers are in the HTML pages.

Comment: @julianobrasil , that will be a workaround if I do not find the solution for this but this is a scenario that should not happen. The authenticated pages and modules should be destroyed after logout.

Comment: The shouldn't be a problem if you destroy the authentication data on logout.

Comment: Something to be aware the route paths are matched in order. I've had issues with empty path index child routes. I register them at the bottom of the array and pathMatch set to full.

Comment: As an experiment you could also try making empty path route a redirect to a named route.

Comment: @TapasMukherjee try to add pathMatch: 'full' to your login route.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easiest solution that would work, you should navigate to the route with "replaceUrl" NavigationExtras

> this.router.navigate(['/home'], { replaceUrl: true });

This replaces the current state in the history, and therefore your Login page will be destroyed. Basically it sets a new root.

[Reference](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl)

Comment: I tried with 'replaceUrl: true' option before with method navigatebyurl  but sometimes the navigation to home page from login page was not working properly and I did not find a proper solution to that but it's working now with navigate method. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The seemingly unexpected behavior you are describing is due to Ionic. More specifically, it is due to [how Ionic deals with the life of a page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#how-ionic-handles-the-life-of-a-page).

> When you navigate to a new page, Ionic will keep the old page in the
>   existing DOM, but hide it from your view and transition the new page.

...

> Because of this special handling, the ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy
>   methods might not fire when you would usually think they should.
>
> ngOnInit will only fire each time the page is freshly created, but not
>   when navigated back to the page. For instance, navigating between each
>   page in a tabs interface will only call each page's ngOnInit method
>   once, but not on subsequent visits. ngOnDestroy will only fire when a
>   page "popped".

Without knowing much about your application, I would suggest using the [Ionic Lifecycle events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#ionic-page-events) instead of the Angular ones for your page components. It sounds like you can probably just replace `ngOnInit` with `ionViewWillEnter` and replace `ngOnDestroy` with `ionViewWillLeave` or `ionViewDidLeave`.

Further down in the documentation is some useful [guidance for each lifecycle method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#guidance-for-each-life-cycle-method)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. It worked with using the 'replaceUrl: true' option. Lifecycle hooks will do the job but I also have to write extra code for cleanup and initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the problem for destroying the previous page.
In Iconic when you navigate to the other page, it still maintains the previous one in the DOM.

So your ngOnDestroy() is not being called.

You can just replace your **navigate()** function to the **navigateRoot()**. This would resolve your issue and would completely gets destroyed.

So your line of codes should be somewhat look like:

```
 this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.router.navigateRoot('home');
  } else {
    this.router.navigateRoot('index');
  }
 });
```

I hope this would resolve your issue.

Comment: There are no function called navigateRoot for Router.